# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mechanicalsoup' / working in command line but not in script

Tags: python, linux, module, mechanicalsoup

I just tried mechanicalsoup in python through the command line and it worked.
However, if I put it in a script I get the error that the module is not found.
System: Linux/Openhabian. There is a python 2.7 and a python3 version as well installed. I tried it with the python3 version of course but I get this one:

```
File "script.py", line 1, in <module>
import mechanicalsoup
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mechanicalsoup'
```

script (though it probably doesn´t help much)

```
import mechanicalsoup
from urllib.request import urlopen
login_page = browser.get("https://www.myurl.com")
browser = mechanicalsoup.Browser()
login_form = login_page.soup.find("form")
login_form.find ("input", {"name": "User"})["value"] = "mylogin"
login_form.find ("input", {"name": "Pass"})["value"] = "mypass"
login_response = browser.submit(login_form, login_page.url)
```

Some linux rights issue or what could cause that?
Thanks.

Comment: Is MechanicalSoup installed ? .............. `pip3 install MechanicalSoup` https://pypi.org/project/MechanicalSoup/

Comment: of course, as mentioned it works in command line mode

Comment: `pip3 install --user MechanicalSoup` → → `python3 expl_qwant.py` from the MechanicalSoup/examples/ https://github.com/MechanicalSoup/MechanicalSoup ......... Seems to work OK.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Do `python3 -m pip install mechanicalsoup` (if on windows)